# Convergence of a series of averages

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series

Suppose, we have a sequence defined like $a_1=10,a_2=20,a_n=\sum\limits_{i=1}^{n-1}\frac{a_i}{n-1}+10\quad n\ge3$. If we restrict the maximum value of $a_i$ to be $100$, what is the maximum value sequence reach to?

Seeing the first few terms of the sequence ($10, 20, 25, 28.33,$), I guess that the sequence is slowly diverging and the sequence may well reach $99$.. Am I right? How do we solve such kind of recurrences. Will the recursion tree method help here? Any hints? Thanks beforehand.

Comment: Can you express $a_{n+1}$ in terms of $a_n$ only?

Comment: If at all it converges it can only converge to $\infty$. $(l=l+10$)

Comment: @KaviRamaMurthy  but here the rate of increase of the sequence decreases sharply

Comment: @SangchulLee yes, edited

Comment: @KaviRamaMurthy ok, what if I restrict $a_i$ s to a maximum of $100$?

Comment: Do you know that if  sequqnce converges so do the Cesaro averages? There is no way this sequence can converge to a finite limit.

Comment: @vidyarthi, Instead of leaving your new question in the comment section, you may update your question with some details. For instance, what exactly do you mean by 'restricting $a_i$'s to a maximum of $100$'?

Comment: You have already specified the entire sequence. You cannot limit $a_n$ to $100$.

Comment: @KaviRamaMurthy yes, silly mistake. I have modified the problem. Please see now

Comment: @SangchulLee done

Comment: @KaviRamaMurthy I mean what is the maximum value of the sequence less than $100$, i.e. what is $max(a_i:a_i<100)$?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Notice that:

\begin{align}a_{n+1} &= \sum_{i=1}^n\frac {a_i}{n}+10
\\&=\frac1n a_n + \frac{n-1}n\sum_{i=1}^{n-1}\frac {a_i}{n-1} + 10
\\&=\frac {a_n}{n} + \frac{n-1}n(a_n-10)+10
\\&=\left(\frac 1n + \frac {n-1}n\right) a_n + 10\left(1-\frac {n-1}n\right)
\\&=a_n+\frac {10}n
\end{align}

so the rate of increase decreases sharply, but not sharp enough, since the harmonic series diverges.

Comment: thanks, but I have just now modified the problem. Please see now

Comment: @vidyarthi, Using this answer, it is not hard to figure out that $a_n=10+10H_{n-1}$, where $H_n=\sum_{k=1}^{n}\frac{1}{k}$ is the $n$th harmonic number. So, $a_n$ is increasing, and $$a_{4550}\approx99.99988283\cdots\qquad\text{and}\qquad a_{4551}\approx 100.0020806\cdots.$$

Comment: @SangchulLee how did you calculate that (value of Harmonic number 4551)? Could you elaborate?,wolframalpha shows $H_{4551}$ to be less than $10$.

Comment: @vidyarthi, There is no known efficient way of computing an exact value of $H_n$ for large $n$. So I simply threw it to a math software to find the index $n=4550$. However, many asymptotic formulas for $H_n$ are know, and that might help you determine an approximate value of $H_n$.

Comment: @SangchulLee got it. Confused with the fact that we multiply $H_n$ by $10$. Wolfram alpha gives the numbers accurately precise